# Show $\left|B^A\right| \cdot \left|B^A\right| = \left|B^A\right|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

> Let $A$, an infinite set such that $\left|A\right|\cdot \left|A\right| = \left|A\right|$ and Let $B$, an arbitrary set. Show $\left|B^A\right| \cdot \left|B^A\right| = \left|B^A\right|$

I'd be glad to get guidance.
Thanks.

**My Try:**

Can we prove it directly by:

$$\left|B^A\right|\times \left|B^A\right| = \left|B\right|^{\left|A\right|} \times \left|B\right|^{\left|A\right|} = \left|B\right|^{\left| A \right| +  \left| A \right|}= \left|B\right|^\left| A \right|$$

Comment: What is $A\rightarrow B$? Seems unusual notation.

Comment: That's the set of all functions from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: @Elimination The more usual notation for that is $B^A$

Comment: Uhh... why the middle equality is true in general? Because if you put finite cardinals there, it's blatantly false. $2^3\cdot 2^3\neq 4^9$.

Comment: Oh I meant $\left|A\right| + \left|A\right|$.

Comment: The base shouldn't change *at all* either.

Comment: Was I just proved it without using the fact that $\left|A\right| \times \left|A\right| = \left|A\right|$?

Comment: No, you use the fact that $|A|^2=|A|$ to obtain $|A|+|A|=|A|$.

Answer (score 1):

As $A$ is infinite, we have $|A|=|A|+|A|$, i.e. there exist a bijection $\phi\colon A\times\{0,1\}\to A$. Then 
$$f\mapsto\langle a\mapsto f(\phi(a,0)), a\mapsto f(\phi(a,1))\rangle$$
is a bijection(!) $B^A\to B^A\times B^A$

Comment: While "as $A$ infinite ..." might not be true in general, it is true here since we assume that $|A|^2=|A|$.

Comment: @Hagen, Could you add an explanation please?